# How to read a queue from ActiveMQ in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, activemq-classic

I tried to return the data from the queue

```py
import stomp
conn = stomp.Connection([('Host','port')])
conn.connect(wait = True)-
print(conn.subscribe('test_queue', headers={}))
```

But I get the error

```
----> 3 print(conn.subscribe('test_queue', headers={}))
TypeError: subscribe() missing 1 required positional argument: 'id'
```

Comment: There error message clearly indicates what the problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error says that `id` parameter is missing.

In the [document](https://jasonrbriggs.github.io/stomp.py/api.html), you can find info.

> id (str) – the identifier to uniquely identify the subscription

You can set for example `123` as a unique id and use the id when unsubscribe.

```
from stomp import *
c = Connection([('127.0.0.1', 62613)])
....
c.subscribe('/queue/test', 123)
c.unsubscribe(123)
```